# Would all questions from the Cell Culture Area 51 proposal be on topic here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

The proposal for [Cell Culture](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/39091/cell-culture) was created a couple of days ago.  From their description

> Proposed Q&A site for anyone involved in the use or research of plant, animal and microbial cell culture including micropropagation, animal tissue and organ replacement, stem cell culture and development and production of metabolic compounds using bioreactors.

It sounds like the questions would be right on topic here (and in fact, I have taken some liberties to simply invite the proposers to Bio.SE).  Another Area 51 user has gone as far as saying that their proposal is a duplicate of Bio.SE.

However, despite the above description, some of their proposed questions tell a different story, and seem to straddle the Biology and Gardening and Landscaping sites.

For example, http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/39091/cell-culture/39095#39095:

> What's the best culture media and environment (light/temp/container) for growing Cattleya orchids?

My only qualm is I don't know how to classify that question and the others like it.  I know there are a few plant experts around, so we certainly have the know-how, but would something like that still be considered on topic here?

Comment: Plant bio is still biology according to some people.

Comment: @bobthejoe You have no argument on that here.  I was concerned that the microculture questions might be more valuable on a highly applied gardening site more than a site that might appeal to someone experimenting with horticulture for research purposes.  Not knowing enough about either subfield, so I'm deferring to any plant experts on our site to make a distinction.

Comment: I'm trying to be cautious about it because there was some impetus to have an independent proposal.  Since my invitation to bring the questions here has gone unanswered, I want to make sure that we're not "tractor-beaming" the questions in where if they are not appropriate.  I was recently part of a proposal that was subsumed into another site, so I understand the thought process of the stakeholders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I think you're completely right in that 95% of content for that proposal would be ably dealt with here - the remainder could either be attempted by our community or given to Gardening, decisions that could be made on a case by case basis (as they are currently) at least until we set a precedent.